# FastAPI dependency with arguments produce unexpected error

Tags: python, dependency-injection, parameters, fastapi

With the following `FastAPI` endpoint:

```
@access_route.get("")
async def get_access_index(request: Request, context: Annotated[Context, Depends(get_context_async)]):
    #...
```

And the following dependency:

```
async def get_context_async() -> Context:
    return dummy_context
```

Everything seems to work as expected, but as soon as I introduce a **parameter** to my dependency like so:

```
@access_route.get("")
async def get_access_index(request: Request, context: Annotated[Context, Depends(get_context_async(required_scopes=["some_scope"]))]):
    #...

async def get_context_async(required_scopes: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> Context:
    # Use required_scopes here
    return dummy_context
```

The code fails at load time with the following error:

```
File "/app/overwatch/access/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
  @access_route.get("")
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 704, in decorator
  self.add_api_route(
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 643, in add_api_route
  route = route_class(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 489, in __init__
  self.dependant = get_dependant(path=self.path_format, call=self.endpoint)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 268, in get_dependant
  sub_dependant = get_param_sub_dependant(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 111, in get_param_sub_dependant
  return get_sub_dependant(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 147, in get_sub_dependant
  sub_dependant = get_dependant(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 250, in get_dependant
  endpoint_signature = get_typed_signature(call)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py", line 208, in get_typed_signature
  signature = inspect.signature(call)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 3280, in signature
  return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped,
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 3028, in from_callable
  return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/inspect.py", line 2449, in _signature_from_callable
  raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: <coroutine object get_context_async at 0x7f1aaa69b920> is not a callable object
```

Now suddenly it seems that my dependency is no longer good enough and I don't know why. My good AI friends suggest that I have to wrap my dependency in a function like so:

```
# Helper dependency
def context_dependency(required_scopes: Optional[List[str]] = None):
    async def dependency():
        return await get_context_async(required_scopes=required_scopes)
    return dependency
```

I am strugglying to understand why this is at all necessary, and also I feel this will incur a lot of unecessary overhead. I am trying (beleive it or not) to write an efficient application and this context dependency will be all over the place.

Comment: In the first example you're giving `Depends` a function to resolve, in the second version you're calling the function _before giving it to `Depends`_, and instead giving it whatever it returns. In your last example you return a function, which again gives `Depends` a function to call _when it should resolve the dependency_. I.e. you changed what you give to  `Depends` - it needs a callable so it can resolve the dependency when the request comes, and not when the function gets defined.